# How can i make my page responsive to my Accordion?

Tags: html, css, accordion

When my accordion expands , the page doesn't respond to that by expanding too so what happens is that the other tabs of my accordion go over my footer. I am asking how can I reveal the data under each tab without having the remaining tabs to go over the footer.

---

[Here's a picture of the problem that I am having right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOP4T.jpg)

---

**Here's my HTML code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset= "utf-8">
<meta name= "description" content= "this this a website that ">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="Algeria.css">
<title> Algeria </title>

</head>

<body>
 
<header>
<a href="index.html"><img src="logo4.bmp" ></a>
<nav>
<ul>
<ol><a href="About.html">About</a></ol>
<div class="line"></div>
<ol><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></ol>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
<main>
    <div class= "index-banner">
        <h1> Algeria </h1>
    </div>
    
          <div class= "Vline">
         <section class= "box1">Country profile
          <div class="lines"></div>
      <h2>Capital city : Algiers (Alger)</h2>
      <h3>Currency : Algerian Dinar (DZN)</h3>
      <h4>Country calling code : +213</h4>
      <h5>Official languages : Arabic, Berber</h5>      
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box2">
 
  <button class="accordion">Banking & finance Law </button>
  <div class="panel">
        <ul>      
    <li>
      <a href= "C:\xampp\htdocs\rootfolder\Algeria\banking and finance law\Loi 90-10 relative à la monnaie et au crédit.pdf" type= "application/pdf" target="_blank">Loi n°90-10 relative à la monnaie et au crédit</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="C:\xampp\htdocs\rootfolder\Algeria\banking and finance law\Loi N° 17-10 du 11 octobre 2017 complétant l’ordonnance N° 03-11 du 26 aout 2003 relative à la Monnaie et au Crédit.pdf" type= "application/pdf" target="_blank">Loi n° 17-10 du 11 octobre 2017 complétant l’ordonnance N° 03-11 du 26 aout 2003 relative à la Monnaie et au Crédit</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="C:\xampp\htdocs\rootfolder\Algeria\banking and finance law\Règlement N°2012-03 du 28 Novembre 2012 relative à la lutte contre le blanchiment des capitaux et le financement du terrorisme.pdf" type= "application/pdf" target="_blank">Règlement n°2012-03 du 28 Novembre 2012 relative à la lutte contre le blanchiment des capitaux et le financement du terrorisme</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="C:\xampp\htdocs\rootfolder\Algeria\banking and finance law\Règlement n° 20-04 relative aux conditions bancaires applicables aux opérations de change.pdf" type= "application/pdf" target="_blank">Règlement n° 20-04 relative aux conditions bancaires applicables aux opérations de change</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="C:\xampp\htdocs\rootfolder\Algeria\banking and finance law\Ordonnance N° 03-11 DU 26 août 2003 relative à la Monnaie et au Crédit.pdf" type= "application/pdf" target="_blank">Ordonnance n° 03-11 du 26 août 2003 relative à la Monnaie et au Crédit</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="C:\xampp\htdocs\rootfolder\Algeria\banking and finance law\Ordonnance N° 10-04 du 26 août 2010 modifiant et complétant l’ordonnance N° 03-11 du  26 août 2003 relative à la Monnaie et au Crédit.pdf" type= "application/pdf" target="_blank">Ordonnance n° 10-04 du 26 août 2010 modifiant et complétant l’ordonnance n° 03-11 du  26 août 2003 relative à la Monnaie et au Crédit</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="C:\xampp\htdocs\rootfolder\Algeria\banking and finance law\Instruction N°08-96 du 18 Décembre 1996 relative aux conditions de création et d'agrèment des bureaux de change.pdf" type= "application/pdf" target="_blank">Instruction n°08-96 du 18 Décembre 1996 relative aux conditions de création et d'agrèment des bureaux de change</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="C:\xampp\htdocs\rootfolder\Algeria\banking and finance law\Instruction N°02-2007 du 31 Mai 2007 Relative aux Opérations Liées aux transactions courantes avec l'étranger.pdf" type= "application/pdf" target="_blank">Instruction n°02-2007 du 31 Mai 2007 Relative aux Opérations Liées aux transactions courantes avec l'étranger</a></li>
</ul>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">Commercial Law </button>
  <div class="panel">
        <ul>
    <li><a href="C:\xampp\htdocs\rootfolder\Algeria\Comercial law\Code du commerce.pdf" type="application/pdf" target="_blank" >Code du commerce</a></li>
    <li> <a href="C:\xampp\htdocs\rootfolder\Algeria\Comercial law\القانون التجـاري.pdf"type="application/pdf" target="_blank">القانون التجـاري</a></li>
    <li><a href="C:\xampp\htdocs\rootfolder\Algeria\Comercial law\Loi n° 90-22 relative au registre de commerce.pdf" type="application/pdf" target="_blank">Loi n° 90-22 relative au registre de commerce</a></li>
    <li><a href="C:\xampp\htdocs\rootfolder\Algeria\Comercial law\Loi n° 2004-02 relative aux règles applicable aux pratiques commerciales.pdf" type="application/pdf" target="_blank" >Loi n° 2004-02 relative aux règles applicable aux pratiques commerciales</a></li>
    <li><a href="C:\xampp\htdocs\rootfolder\Algeria\Comercial law\Loi n° 2004-08 relative aux conditions d'exercice activites commerciales.pdf" type="application/pdf" target="_blank" >Loi n° 2004-08 relative aux conditions d'exercice activites commerciales</a></li>
    <li><a href="C:\xampp\htdocs\rootfolder\Algeria\Comercial law\Loi n°2018-05 relative au commerce electronique.pdf" type="application/pdf" target="_blank" >Loi n°2018-05 relative au commerce electronique</a></li>
    <li><a href="C:\xampp\htdocs\rootfolder\Algeria\Comercial law\Décret-2019-89 relatif aux modalités de conservation et de transmission des registres des transactions commerciales électroniques au centre national du registre de commerce.pdf" type="application/pdf" target="_blank" >Décret-2019-89 relatif aux modalités de conservation et de transmission des registres des transactions commerciales électroniques au centre national du registre de commerce</a></li>
    <li><a href="C:\xampp\htdocs\rootfolder\Algeria\Comercial law\Ordonnance n 96-07 modifiant et complétant la loi n 90-22 relative au registre de commerce.pdf" type="application/pdf" target="_blank" >Ordonnance n 96-07 modifiant et complétant la loi n 90-22 relative au registre de commerce</a></li>
</ul>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">Civil Law </button>
  <div class="panel">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="C:\xampp\htdocs\rootfolder\Algeria\civil law\Code civil.pdf"type="application/pdf" target="_blank" >Code civil</a></li>
          <li><a href="C:\xampp\htdocs\rootfolder\Algeria\civil law\القانون الـمدنـي.pdf"type="application/pdf" target="_blank" >Code du commerce</a></li>
          <li><a href=type="application/pdf" target="_blank" >Code du commerce</a></li>
          <li><a href=type="application/pdf" target="_blank" >Code du commerce</a></li>


   
</ul>
  </div>    
  <button class="accordion">Competition Law </button>
  <div class="panel">
        <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Learn More</a></li>
</ul>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">Consumer Law </button>
  <div class="panel">
        <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Learn More</a></li>
</ul>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">Criminal Law </button>
  <div class="panel">
        <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Learn More</a></li>
</ul>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">Employment Law </button>
  <div class="panel">
        <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Learn More</a></li>
</ul>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">Family Law </button>
  <div class="panel">
        <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Learn More</a></li>
</ul>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">Intellectual property Law </button>
  <div class="panel">
        <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Learn More</a></li>
</ul>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">Tax Law </button>
  <div class="panel">
        <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Learn More</a></li>
</ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
      var i;

      for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
          this.classList.toggle("active");
          var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
          if (panel.style.maxHeight){
            panel.style.maxHeight = null;
          } else {
            panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
          } 
        });
      }
</script>
  </script>
      
        
 
        </main>
    
        <footer>
            Copyright © 2020 Africa Law. All rights reserved. Terms of Use
       </footer> 
     
       </body>
       </html>
```

**Here's my CSS code**

```
 *{
text-decoration: none;
}
body {
  background-color: white;  
 }
header {
    background-color:white ;
    width: 100% ;
    height: 120px;
 }

 img {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 512px;
 margin-left:60px;

}
 header nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 510px;
    right: 200px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: fit-content;
    color: rgb(230, 227, 227);
}
header nav ul ol {
    font-family: Playfair display ;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #111;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 16px;
 
}
.line {
    border-left : 2px solid silver;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 44%;
    margin-left: -1px;
    top: 0;
   


}
.lines {
    border-bottom : 3px solid silver;
    height: 10px;
    width: 110px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
header nav ul ol a {
    font-family: Playfair display;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #111;

}
    header .languages {
    display: none; 
    }
/*INDEX*/
.index-banner {
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.index-banner {
width: 100%;
height: 50vh;
background-image: url('coverpage.jpg.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
display: table;


 }
 .index-banner h1 {
    font-family: Playfair display;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 150px;
    left: 580px;
    
    /*text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px white;*/
    

 }
  

/* Styling Country*/

/*.container {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
flex-direction: row;
height: 700px;
background: rgba(214,221,229,1) ;
width: 100%;
}*/
.wrapper{
    display: inline-block;
   
   

}
.Vline {
    height: 800px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: -15px;
    background-color: rgba(214,221,229,1) ;
    overflow: hidden;
    
  
}
.box1 {
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 10px black;
    width: 77%;
    height: 18%;
    /*background-color:#7d93b0;*/
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}



h2,h3,h4,h5 {
    border-radius: 1px;
    margin: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 3px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: black;
    background-color: whitesmoke;

}
h2:hover,h3:hover,h4:hover,h5:hover {
background-color:#b0c7e6;
transition: ease-in 0.1s;
box-shadow:0 0 2rem 0 rgb(246, 233, 185);
cursor: pointer;
}
h2 {
    margin-top: 9px;
}
/* Accordion*/
/* Style the buttons that are used to open and close the accordion panel */
.accordion {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid white;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.4s;
    font: 18px Lato, arial;
}

/* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
.active, .accordion:hover {
    background-color: #7d93b1;
}

/* Style the accordion panel. Note: hidden by default */
.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
   
   
}


.accordion:after {
    content: "\2B9B"; 
    font-size: 18px;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
    content: "\2B99";
}
.box2 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 80px;
    right:80px;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70%;
    line-height: 50px;
   

   
}
li {
    list-style: none;

}
 li:before {
    content: "♦";
    padding-right: 13px;
    color: #7d93b1;
}
a {
color: #38485c;
}

footer {
   padding: 12px;
   background-color: black; 
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your containers have `position: absolute`, not static. Result is that it doesnt take space to the parent container.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however when I did that my box is not positioned in the middle but rather in bottom. How can I fix that? because I have used position: absolute to position the box in the middle of the page now after changing it to static the page does expand automatically but the box is in the bottom

Comment: maybe its because your `.wrapper` class has `display: inline-block`. Try change it to `block` and give your box `margin:0 auto`

Comment: Unfortunately the accordion is still at the bottom, I don't know how to center it in the page. I appreciate your help.

Comment: ok I looked closesly what is in your code. You are trying to put 2 divs next to each other. Read about flex-box and apply it to your design.